# Test for certain amount of item in hand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Are there any commands that can test for a player holding at **least** 3 arrows in his main hand?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could give a tag to te player if they hold an arrow, and remove the tag if they hold only one or two arrows.

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add HoldsArrows {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow"}}
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldsArrows] remove HoldsArrows {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b}}
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldsArrows] remove HoldsArrows {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:2b}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1.13+ Update to [Aeldrion's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/315015/250180)

- `/scoreboard players tag` has been replaced with `/tag`.

1.13+ commands:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add HoldsArrows {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow"}}
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldsArrows] remove HoldsArrows {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b}}
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=HoldsArrows] remove HoldsArrows {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:2b}}
```