# How to detect if somebody is holding something while activating a noteblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm building a map with right-click detection via a noteblock and I have this command:

```
/execute if block 21 107 38 minecraft:note_block[note=1] if entity @p[x=21,y=107,z=38,nbt={SelectedItem:[{id:"minecraft:arrow"}]}] run say hi
```

But when I'm holding an arrow while making the noteblock go to note one, the command doesn't fire.

Comment: You have to track the statistic [`stat.noteblockTuned`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Scoreboard#Criteria) and also [check for the item in the hand](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315014/test-for-certain-amount-of-item-in-hand). If you need a full answer, please tell me.

Comment: Archive link for the first link in my last comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Scoreboard&oldid=1260975#Criteria

Answer (score -1):

It'll only run if the players coordinates are the same as the note block chords.

```
/execute if block **21 107 38** minecraft:note_block[note=1] if entity @p[x=**21**,y=**107**,z=**38**,nbt={SelectedItem:[{id:"minecraft:arrow"}]}] run say hi
```

If it doesn't matter where they are, remove x y and z from inside the square brackets, if it does matter change the coordinates.

You also have to add `distance=..1`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's asking about how to detect activating a note block while holding an arrow.

Comment: It should now work if you are holding the arrow, so it kind of does.

Comment: But your answer has nothing to do with note blocks!